# Joining two polygons that have information in same spatial location using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, polygon, spatial-join

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1.

I have two shapefiles, one that has human disturbance and one that is fishnet grid and every grid has a unique value. I used the fishnet tool on my human disturbance shapefile, to create grids of the same size so that for each grid I can say how much area within a grid is human disturbance.

How do I join these two shapefiles, so that I can have the unique value from one shapefile and the human disturbance of the other all in the same polygon?

I have tried spatial join and merge, and they have both returned null values.

Comment: Keep playing with spatial join.  It should work for this purpose.  Try different match options.  Also make sure that your shapefiles are using the same coordinate system.

Comment: Can you reflect on a bit more please: *I'd like to join these two shapefiles, so that I can have the unique value from one shapefile and the human disturbance of the other all in the same polygon.*?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is the spatial join tool, but apparently it didn't work? much information is needed, like; are the features in the same coordinate projection? if not, try using project tool first on one of the feature, to the same coordinate system of other feature, for example, WGS 1984. or project them both to one coordinate system.
Then do spatial join.
I hope this works!